# Duplicate depending in Excel rows

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns (2 on 1 sheet - 2 on other):

`Paris France Paris 1732 
 Marseilles France Moscow 214 
 Moscow Russia Lublin 1412 
 Kharkiv Ukraine Milan 24421 
 Ohaio... US... Oslo...42141`

And i need add "country" column (i mean synchronize with "city column) on sheet number 2.
How can i did it? Big thanx.

Comment: Insert a column and use an appropriate formula. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I like the example better than those screenshots that are shown in many other questions because it can be copied to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a column and use this function:

`=VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet1!$A$1:$B$5;2;0)`

(assuming that the first sheet is called Sheet1 and that the data are in cells A1:B5)